# Flattening Array[Array[String]] to Array[String]

Tags: scala

I would like to flattening my data structure of type Array[Array[String]] to Array[String] where there are some empty Array() too.

For example:

```
val test=Array(Array("foo"), Array("bar"), Array(),...)
```

To be converted to:

```
Array(foo,bar,"")
```

I tried :

```
test.flatMap(x=>x.toString())
```

But this gets broken down into char array:

> Array([f, o, o,..])

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using

```
test.flatten
```

The reason your initial approach didn't work is that `x` in `x=>x.toString()` is an `Array[String]` so each `Array` will become the string representation of that `Array`

Comment: This is what I initially tried but it gives me `value flatten is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]]
`

Comment: @JasimWaheed : then what you have is probably not a Array[Array[String]] but a RDD[Array[String]], which is different. I think you should edit your question and title with this information if that's the case, and maybe add the apache-spark tag.

Comment: @Jasim Waheed, if it's a RDD, use flatMap like `sc.parallelize(test).flatMap(x => x)`.